# Insert on condition update sql

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to Update a table if condition is met, if not then just to insert the record.

I tried this code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table.person WHERE record_id='SomeValue')
    UPDATE table.person 
    SET some_text='new_some_text', some_other_text='some_other_text' 
    WHERE record_id='old_record_id'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table.person (record_id, person_id, some_text, some_other_text) 
    VALUES ('new_record_id', 'new_person_id', 'new_some_text', 'new_some_other_text')
```

but this only returns an error for me. The error I get back is general syntax error.

Error response:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE table.person SET some_text='new_some_text', some_other_text='some_o' at line 2

Comment: please post the full error message (there are more details).

Comment: If you are using MySQL then you have to write above code inside the function or stored procedure only.

Comment: `IF` _statements_ can used only in stored routines, not general client code.  If this is already in a SP, then you are missing a `THEN`.  But, switch to IODKU, as suggested by Willy_Sunny.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, from the looks of this, it this is a typical UPSERT (Insert or Update) question.

Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Based on your example, `record_id` is most likely your primary key.

So your code can simply become this.

```
INSERT INTO table.person (record_id, person_id, some_text, some_other_text) 
VALUES ('new_record_id', 'new_person_id', 'new_some_text', 'new_some_other_text')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
some_text='new_some_text', some_other_text='some_other_text';
```

SQLFiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e8c7d7/1/0

Answer (score 0):

In your query "THEN" is missing after the IF

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table.person WHERE record_id='SomeValue') **THEN**
```

Please add "THEN" and check

Also Add the "End If" at the end

Answer (score -1):

I just use num_rows to check already data exist in that posted id.If num_rows greater than zero then update the data with that id, Otherwise insert the data.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= '1'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // ENTER UPDATE QUERY
  }
  else{
      // ENTER INSERT QUERY
  }
```

Comment: I am already doing that, if timestamp is during the same day then it happens update, but the later records can include new rows, so to avoid checking in PHP if that line already exists I want to simply write insert on duplicate key update, the problem is that the ID I would want to use for primary key, can not be used as such because it must be set as not unique.